# In AWS where how can I get the list of image ids

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ami

If I need to get list of AMI image ids (Ex: "ami-0ff8a91507f77f867") for **Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type**

Is there a CLI command I can run (prefered) or is it documented some where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AWS managed list of current AMIs for Amazon Linux can be obtained using aws cli and querying public AWS SSM Parameters:

- [Calling AMI Public Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/parameter-store-public-parameters.html#parameter-store-public-parameters-ami)
- [Query for the latest Amazon Linux AMI IDs using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/)

The cool thing is that these values can be referenced in CloudFormation templates, so there is no need to hard-code the AMI ids.

Having the latest AMI ids, one can also use [describe-images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html) AWS CLI command to get more details about them, or filter out those which exhibit properties of interest to you (e.g. Volume Type).